# Setting the onclick event to a custom function results in syntax error

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

Given the following example code I want to set the `onclick` event to a function which I declare in the same method (no function in global scope):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<Title>Title</Title>
</HEAD>
<body>
<img id="img" class="std" src="http://www.free-animated-pictures.com/bug_crawls_on_screen.gif"/>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var i = document.getElementById("img");
var func = function(){
    var i = document.getElementById("img");
    if(i.className === "std"){
        i.className = "hid";
        i.style.display = "none";
    }
    else if(i.className === "hid"){
        i.className = "std";
        i.style.display = "block";
    }
};
//func = func.toString();
//func = func.replace("function ()", "")
document.body.setAttribute("onclick", func);
</script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

If I use the code as is I only get the following error when the event is fired:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

If instead I take the string of the function and remove the **function** part of it, the script works as expected:

```
func = func.toString();
func = func.replace("function ()", "")
```

Why is that so? Is there a better way? Obviously I can't declare the function without the **function** part, so what's the point in removing it again?

Comment: `document.body.onclick = func` don't use `setAttribute` it's not an attribute, well it can be an HTML one but you don't do that from JS.

Comment: are there any drawbacks of document.body.onclick? I remember using someelement.setattribute("onclick", "func(...);"), because someelement.onclick did not always set the onclick event properly or was it just some error of mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were setting the actual textual element's attribute *string* using `setAttribute`, which in turn is auto-wrapped in a function!
Also, if it would have worked, there would be no body to click on once the image had disappeared.

*Here is a working example **you should not use**, just intended to explain above statement*:

Here is a function `func` which is converted to string (and where a string is expected, javascript usually calls the `.toString()` method automatically, I put it in to clearly show what happened).
Then, to prevent a quoting problem (you used double-quotes in html and for some (in my opinion, insane) reason some browsers replace single quotes in javascript to double quotes (and I've even witnessed some pre-compiling in some browsers)), I *naively* (because it was safe for this particular function) replaced all double quotes to single quotes.
Then we still need to remove `function(){` and trailing `}`.
Now we arrived at the function string, which we can pass.
Finally the browser sets the actual textual attribute and wraps the code again inside a function so that it works.

```html
<img id="img" class="std" src="http://www.free-animated-pictures.com/bug_crawls_on_screen.gif" />
intentional text filler, otherwise body shrinks to 0*0 px leaving nothing to click on...
<script type='text/javascript'>
var func = function(){ 
    var i = document.getElementById('img');
    if(i.className === 'std'){
        i.className = 'hid';
        i.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(i.className === 'hid'){
        i.className = 'std';
        i.style.display = 'block';
    }
};

document.body.setAttribute( 'onclick'
                          , func.toString()
                                .replace(/\"/g,'\'')
                                .replace(/^function *\( *\) *{/,'')
                                .replace(/} *$/,'')
                          );
</script>
```

**Solution** is obviously to `document.body.onclick=func` directly (as gillesc already commented), or use `document.body.addEventListener('click',func,false)` (which is what you are probably confused with).

Note that for backward compatibility (notably < IE9) you'd need `attachEvent`, here is a basic [workaround](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/addeventlistenerattachevent.htm):

```
function addEventHandler(elem, eventType, handler) {
 if (elem.addEventListener)
     elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
 else if (elem.attachEvent)
     elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
}
```